# Alternative for ShowDialog in ASP .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Am coming from C#.net, VB.net back ground to ASP.net. I used them for long time; but the current project is in ASP.Net.

I want alternative for ShowDialog. One important feature of showdialog (which I want) was the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Some jquery alternatives for showdialog I have found but they don’t stop execution of code following it (until form or dialog is closed).

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortantly, you really can’t do this.

The problem of course is that the architecture you are using is now a message based system. This quite much forces you to write and adopt what we call asynchronous coding approaches.

And they tend to be “hard” since most of us from our first days with computers?

Well, you call a sub, we wait, that sub runs and THEN it returns and the code next line after continues to run.

We pop a dialog – wait, and then the code next after continues to run. So as humans (developers) most code is “liner” in this fashion, and so are subs, and so are dialogs (at least in desktop land).

But, browser based technology is VERY different. For one, the browser is sitting on your desktop. And the server is way over someplace else.

It is BEYOND critical that the so called “round trip” of how browser software works is grasped. Failure to grasp this simple concept will cause a lot of difficulty in doing what should seem like a everyday simple task. (and such as your question + quest).

You have to keep in mind that the browser system is state-less, but more important is that the browser is sitting on the client side users’ desktop.

You have this:

[image]

You do NOT HAVE THIS!!!

[image]

And you do NOT have this:

[image]

The web page is NOT sitting in memory on the server - I can be loaded, but it is NOT.

We have a user, and their browser. You can close the lid, go browsing on StackOverflow - the server has ZERO knowledge about that browser page JUST SITTING on their desktop.

So, let’s try something really SIMPLE.

We drop a button and a text box on to the web page like this:

[image]

And then we double click on the button, and we now just writing good old vb code - so far everything is much like desktop development.

We write this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello, how are you?" & vbCrLf & "Today is " & Now.ToLongDateString

    Me.TextBox1.Text = s

End Sub
```

And we now run this. We get this:

[image]

But, what really occurred?

Well, user clicks button.

[image]

So this is the START of the so called round trip.

The web page is now sent to the web server and we have this:

[image]

Now the code behind runs - but the browser? It is just sitting here - can not see ANYTHING or changes that your code behind runs. So our above vb code runs (code behend) WHILE the page is parked at the server.

Then after code behind runs, the page travels BACK down to the browser and is then displayed.

we have this:

[image]

There is NOT now a copy of the web page on both ends. ONLY on the client side browser end does the web page exist. And so any variable or anything you did in code behind? Well, it kind of like a exit from a sub - all values and EVERYTHING is now out of scope on the server side. AGAIN: the page does NOT exist on the server side at this point in time in memory - it is NOT loaded anymore!!!).

Note how we can’t HALT that code behind. If you halt the code behind, then the browser is STUCK on the server, and no update or anything at all will or CAN occur or CAN display or CAN happen in the browser. Until the code behind is 100% done then and ONLY then does the browser make the trip back down to the client side.

As a result, you can see that any code that halted, stopped or waited say for a dialog box would not work and could not work. If you code behind “halts”, then the web page is STILL stuck on the server.

You have to think of the code behind as really a FAST “fly by” grab at the web page.

The web page comes up to server. You code now starts to run, can see controls, can modify controls and ONCE done the whole page now goes back down to the client side. But the code you write NEVER really interacted directly with the user.

The code behind ONLY interacts with the web page NOT THE USER!

And the code behind ONLY interacts with that web page WHILE it is in that round trip AND the page is up on the server side.

And only up at server side for a short time during that round trip. Once the code runs THEN and only then does the whole page now make the trip back down to the browser and THEN the browser displays the results of that page. And the server side page NOW DOES NOT exist!!! (Very important here – the code, the values in variables and even the whole web page does NOT exist server side anymore – it is 100% gone gone!!!

If your code halts or stops – then the web page is stuck server side – the browser has ZERO clue as to what is going on!!!

We have ALL written that code that pops a message box. And then we do a classic if/then/else based on the user selection of the choice.

You simply cannot do this.

You code can ONLY respond to the browser - but NOT wait for a a response in code!!!

So, in place of that classic

```
if Msgbox("Do you want to delete") = vbOk then
    ' code here to delete
else
    ' code here if user does not delete
End if
```

The above NOW must become:

```
 code to pop dialog
 
 code stub to run if ok click

 code stub to run if cancel click
```

You in effect wind up with 3 routines. You simply can't have halting code. And if you did halt code behind, then the round trip diagram above needs to be viewed again. The web page will get stuck on the server - the browser "spinning wait" thingy will spin, and you can ONLY get the browser to update AFTER you code behind is done, the subs + code exits, and all the things you wanted changed on the web page are DONE and THEN and ONLY then does the page go back to client side and THEN the browser dispalys and re-plots the whole page.

And this means if you have a simple button on a web form, and you want a confirmation dialog (ok to run or delete, or cancel code to not?). Well, then if you using browser side say jQuery dialog, or jQuery.UI (which I use), then again that code CAN'T hault.

You can use alert() or confirm client side to halt js code, but that is VERY rare ability - all new browser code, and that includes wigets and the gazillion "dialog" libraries that you can find out there? Like "toast" messages or jQuery.UI dialogs? They don't halt code.

So you will in JS

display the dialog - no blocking code.

And now the user clicks on "ok" or "yes" or "approve", and then a separate js code stub will run and that code can then click your button you dropped on the form and then run the code behind.

Once you read/see/grasp that round trip diagram above? You quite much see how and why your search or quest for a old style desktop "blocking" code, and the nice + easy if/then/else that follows that dialog is NOT possbile.

So will you miss this nice ability of the desktop ? yes, you have to code around it - but you WILL have to code this out differnt.

so , no blocking code. And you simple now need two code stubs - one for cancel, and one for ok or whatever.

I do often take a existing asp.net button. I "hide" it with style="display:none".

I then create the dialog (say jQuery.ui - so that will be a "div" section). I then add a new button. You click on that button, and then that dialog either does nothing, or does a js "click" on the existing button I had. So you get the same effect - and with  not too much effort.